# Easier way to print in bold a string variable in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, text

Today I'm having a *very* specific issue: I want to print a string variable inside a function using `plt.text()` in bold. I feel I'm pushing Python's graphing capabilities to the limit when mixing `mathtext` with the usual syntax.

So, the important part of the function looks like this:

```
def graph_text(var):
    string0=f'String is:'+r"$\bf{"+var+"}$"
    plt.text(string0)
```

The thing is `var` are some strings that can have between one and three words. By default in `mathtext` strings are concatenated, so, for `var='the dog'` this would print 'String is **thedog**'.

I then tried using `split()` and `'\/\'.join()`, like this:

```
string0=f'String is:'+r"$\bf{"+('\/\'.join(var.split()))+"}$"
```

( '\/\' is a space in `mathtext`, but because here we're outside of `mathtext` syntax, this is interpreted as a scape character and brings a `SyntaxError`. So, the only solution I could find is to manually do it like this:

```
 if len(var)==1:
    string0=f'String is:'+r"$\bf{"+var.split()[0]+"}$"
elif len(var)==2:
    string0=f'String is:'+r"$\bf{"+var.split()[0]+r" $\bf{"+var.split()[1]+"}$"
else:
    (insert same code but for three words)
```

So, do you know if there's a way to do it without having to account for every possible case? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When writing LaTeX documents I use `\;` to put a space when in math mode.  It also appears to work here.

```
plt.text(0,0,r'String is $\bf{{{}}}$'.format(var.replace(' ', r'\;')))
```

I suggest using `str.format()` instead of concatenating your strings because it makes your intent clearer the next time you look at it.

Comment: Almost the same answer I would have written after looking at e.g. this site: https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Spacing_in_math_mode

Comment: Just one question, why do you use triple brackets (`{{{}}}`) instead of a simple bracket?

Comment: @juan-c `{}` is used to indicate something will be substituted by `.format()`.  When you literally need a `{` to persist in your final string you escape it by doubling it with `{{`.  Have a look at the [official docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings) and this [useful website](https://pyformat.info/)